# PHP array with for loop

Tags: php

i have array of 10 item and each item has own price.

i have to select some item and display the selected item's average and if any of selected item's above the average i have to display it's pic in 2x2 table different pic in each cell.

i write this code but the problem is the pic repeat in the 4 cell's:

```
    <?php
echo "<table border=2>";
$incVar = 0;
for ($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++) {
    echo"<tr>";

    for ($y = 0; $y < 2; $y++) {

        echo"<td>";
        while($incVar <=9){
        if (isset($camera[$incVar]) && $camera[$incVar] >= $avreag){
                echo '<img src="' . $pic[$incVar] . '" width="200" height="200">';
            }
        $incVar++;
    }

        echo "</td>";
    }


    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of second `for` loop (with `$y` var)?

Comment: first for and the second is to display the table 2 column, 2 row

Comment: so what are you trying to achieve in that case? what do you have in `$camera` array and `$avreag` variable? post them as well.

Comment: in camera array i have cheek box with 10 item , in avreag i have the avreage price for selected item. if need to display table of 2x2 pic if the sleeted camera price is above the average.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create image array because if you will display in this manner and if some items does not match the condition then it will leave blank `<td>` 
solution :

```
<?php
echo "<table border=2>";
$incVar = 0;
for ($x = 0; $x < 2; $x++) {
    echo"<tr>";

    for ($y = 0; $y < 2; $y++) {
        echo"<td>";
        if (isset($camera[$incVar]) && $camera[$incVar] >= $avreag) {
                echo '<img src="' . $pic[$incVar] . '" width="200" height="200">';
            }
        $incVar++;
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

no you need to display `$imagesArr` in 4x4 for loop

Comment: i need to display 4 cell and if 1 utem match the conduction it will display the img if not it will be blank

Comment: i edit my code can you please cheek it . still the selected pic shown in one cell only.

Comment: change the condition of for loop `$x < 2` , you will get final result